# The most suitable HTTP method for polling a queue

Tags: rest, http, web, queue

What I've got here is one small interesting question which has already poured tons of confusion on me - so I hope someone will make it clear finally;)

Imagine there is a web server that holds some list of items. So if you want to implement a REST service you will probably choose to add a `GET` method for `http://webservice.com/items` resource or something like that I guess.

**Problem is**: what if that collection is not just a list anymore but a queue? And a client should be able to poll it? For example: first request will retrieve 10 items (and they will be automatically dropped from the collection), second request will retrieve next 10 items and so on..?

**What is the most suitable HTTP verb for such operation?**

Comment: you could use a HTTP cookie to keep track of the number of items sent so far. SO on the next GET request which includes the cookie, you would parse the cookie, find out the number of items you have sent so far and now send the next 10

Comment: @YSU, thanks for answer, but it's not what I'm actually looking for. There is a real queue on the server and it is being polled by any client who can access it. The main problem here is to choose correct verb: is it GET, or maybe DELETE..?

Comment: According to REST principle `DELETE` verb should return `NoContent` status code in case of successful deletion of the specified resource. In your case you are getting the resource you actually want but after that the resource no longer exists. I think you should stick with `GET` verb.